# How do I create one row from two rows of data in R? (Bracket example)

Tags: r, dplyr

I start with a data frame we will call DF1:

```
Team       Stat1     Stat2     Stat3    Stat4      Pod
Georgia        1         3         3        6        1
Nevada         2         2         2        7        2
Clemson        3         1         2        4        2
Texas          5         4         2        3        1
```

I want to use only Stats 1,2,3 (not 4). Based on the value in "Pod" I want to create a row with two teams. Each team would have Stats 1, 2, and 3. It should look something like this:

```
Team1     Stat1A     Stat2A     Stat3A     Team2     Stat1B     Stat2B     Stat3B
Georgia        1          3         3      Texas          5         4           2
Nevada         2          2         2      Clemson        3         1           2
```

This is supposed to indicate that Georgia and Texas are playing one another, Nevada and Clemson are playing, and so on. For every round in the tourney I would have to re-assign pods to the matchups in order to progress through the bracket. So, in this very simplified bracket example, the winner of each of the games would play, let's say Georgia faces Clemson in the final to get this:

```
Team1     Stat1A     Stat2A     Stat3A     Team2     Stat1B     Stat2B     Stat3B
Georgia        1          3         3      Clemson        3         1           2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1[-5]), Pod ~ LETTERS[rowid(Pod)], 
      value.var = names(df1)[1:4], sep="") 
#    Pod   TeamA   TeamB Stat1A Stat1B Stat2A Stat2B Stat3A Stat3B
#1:   1 Georgia   Texas      1      5      3      4      3      2
#2:   2  Nevada Clemson      2      3      2      1      2      2
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use aggregate from base R:

```
aggregate(.~Pod,df[-5],I)
  Pod  Team.1  Team.2 Stat1.1 Stat1.2 Stat2.1 Stat2.2 Stat3.1 Stat3.2
1   1 Georgia   Texas       1       5       3       4       3       2
2   2  Nevada Clemson       2       3       2       1       2       2
```

If you need an exact match then:

```
s=do.call(data.frame,aggregate(.~Pod,df[-5],I))
s[c(grep("\\.1",names(s)),grep("\\.2",names(s)))]
   Team.1 Stat1.1 Stat2.1 Stat3.1  Team.2 Stat1.2 Stat2.2 Stat3.2
1 Georgia       1       3       3   Texas       5       4       2
2  Nevada       2       2       2 Clemson       3       1       2
```